# Upload file and add its content to a table on a web page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I need to create a component on a web page to import an excel file so that the data it contains can be inserted into a table. This requires me to send the file to the server, extract the data and send the data back to be inserted into a table. I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 on the server side.

I got the file upload working without using Ajax and I performed the data extraction using an OleDB connection to access the file. The issue surrounds sending the data back to be inserted into the table. I had assumed I could use the Ajax.BeginForm() helper method for uploading the file but this apparently does not work for file uploads (anyone able to tell me why?). So I need to find a way for sending the data back to the client using Ajax. Googling around I've found many tools for ajax enabled file uploaders. The one I've looked at using is :

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

This works by returning a json success message when the file is uploaded. This does not fit with what I'm trying to do because I don't want to store the file on the server but instead want to pass the data back. I'm only learning JavaScript and JQuery so I'm wondering can I just return the data in json format instead and create a handler on the client side to add it to a table? I'd appreciate any code snippets or direction on how to achieve this.

Alternatively if there is a better approach to doing this I'd be happy to change my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the ajax upload toolkit you mentioned.  But your question doesn't really explain where you're stuck, but what you're trying to accomplish.  You're able to upload to the server, but are you able to return the correct JSON?

Once you get that part working, it looks like that toolkit allows you to set a `OnComplete` function:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){},
```

which would allow you to take the `responseJSON` and populate your table as you see fit.  For example (albeit not the greatest):

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJson){
    $(responseJson).each(function(){    
        $('#yourTable').append('<tr><td>' + this + </td></tr>')
    });
}
```

Here's another good link on the subject: http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/

And here's a hanselman link with probably more detail that you're looking for: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx

Comment: i don't think he have upload problems

Comment: Apologies if I didn't make my issue clear enough. Using the ajax upload toolkit I can return json data. My issue was how do I then approach handling the returned data. I was unsure if I had to wrest control of the post back from the upload toolkit but I think that was poor understanding on my part. Your answer and the links you provided give me a much better idea of how I need to approach the task of returning the json data and inserting it in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Upload the file into some custom temporary folder in your server giving it a random filename
2. when upload is complete, create a table from that using ASP (in the specified page itself. I mean modify your main page using data collected from file)
3. after creating the table, delete the file and do the rest